# Routing scenarios possible with AMQP but not with JMS API

Tags: jms, amqp

I've faced a really big trouble arguing about JMS vs RabbitMQ AMQP and need your help.

So my question is - are there some scenarios which can be solved using AMQP 0.9.1 protocol but not with JMS? I'm talking about routing and message handling. Probably you know something else.

I really love RabbitMQ and want to choose it as our micro-services platform messaging mechanism, but our architects say there nothing special in AMQP and JMS API is better.

The main difference here is that AMQP is a protocol and JMS is an API, so using AMQP we can be platform independent not being stuck with Java.

But I wonder if there are some killer-features and opportunities which JMS doesn't have.

Comment: Start reading; for example [here](http://www.wmrichards.com/amqp.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

JMS is just a API while AMQP is a protocol. So your first point is very correct , JMS (Providers) is mostly java bounded but RabbitMQ is not. Routing is the most powerful feature which you will not find in typical JMS providers. RabbitMQ is easy to scale and performance is far better than JMS providers in the market. It is built over Erlang, which is good at memory utilization and scaling. (Whatapp's backend is based on Erlang). You can add various opensource plugins to RabbitMQ or write your own if needed to solve specific problems. Few tips to convince your architects :

1: SCALING: Scale your fav JMS server and then do the same for RabbitMQ

2: ROUTING :How much effort to implement a routing logic in JMS server vs 
   RabbitMQ (Might be for JMS you have to write some custom code)

3: PERFORMANCE : How many concurrent connections you can make with a JMS vs 
   RabbitMQ and also do a load testing

4: PLUGINS: Show few common plugins and their features to add additional 
   features to your messaging infrastructure

RabbitMQ provides a nice web based admin console.You can find all the connections and memory usages, queue depth and cluster details from the same console. They will love and it alson provides REST API as well as CLI to do the same. Finally, RabbitMQ is very simple and powerful.

Reference : http://www.wmrichards.com/amqp.pdf